# T-SQL Temp Table Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

At my current contractor job, I have come across something I have never seen before in SQL performance.

There is a report that takes most of the day, or the entire day to run. Can return about 5 million records. I was charged with trying to improve the speed of the report. I checked the execution plan and every join hits an index. I am seeing index seeks and scans on every thing. The only thing I see that may be an issue is the stats might be a bit off. The query is pretty complex, but I have a lot of the messages turned on so I can see it as it loads temp tables.

Also, the query uses no CTE's, it does a pivot about midway through and only has two parameters for date ranges in it. It only hits one database, so no link servers or open queries.

So I did some further experiments. I ran the query and instead of letting the result set output, I just sent it to a temp table. A simple into #temp. It finished in about two minutes or so, about 5 million records loaded. So then I thought I would do a select * from #temp and this thing has been running for hours. Just to get 5 million records out of the temp table. Index at this point shouldn't matter as it should do a table scan anyway.

What is interesting is that the the result shows up almost instantly from the temp table, but really starts to slow down as it progresses.

So I figured I would try something else. I have my own Microsoft SQL Server Express instance and created a recursive CTE to create a one attribute table with 5 million rows with the values for the one attribute from 1 to 5 million. On my local instance, it takes about 30 to 40 seconds. On the production server, the exact same recursive CTE takes about 4 to 5 minutes to run. That is a massive difference. Multiple runs and these numbers hold fairly steady.

This company keeps what is running on the server to themselves so I don't know what processes are running during the day.

Out of nearly ten years of doing this kind of work, I have never seen this behavior before. I thought it might have been a network communication issue, but I had other employees who have machines on prem try the same query and result was the same. One developer had an out of memory error.

I am thinking this is a server resource issue. It seems getting data from the temp table is the bottle neck. So, for those that have done this for much longer and know way more than me, what is going on here with trying to get data out of temp tables?

Tried recursive CTE to test performance between a local server instance and prod. Local instance was significantly faster than prod. Had other employee's try running the query and they had the same long query execution times. One had an out of memory error. I tried searching this site for this specific example of performance issues, found nothing. Google search yield no solutions either.

Comment: Great investigation. So you need to focus on why it takes so long to return data from a 5 million row table. But the first question is: what human can possibly make sense of a report with 5 million records? Is this actually just a data export to be loaded into excel or some other downstream system? I think we can assume this problem will be repeated for _any_ 5 million row table. I suggest you check out sql server waits and see if there is anything obvious. There might be I/O waits or network waits. Where is the report server that is making use of this data?

Comment: You could also try running a BCP export from the temp table and run that locally on the SQL Server. That will take network out of the equation. If it's quick, you know network is the issue

Comment: Sounds like you really need to look into the waits on this instance, it could well be due to underlying hardware or virtualization problems. I've seen hideous performance from SQL Servers hosted on ESX/i virtualization where the I/O quotas were apparently limited to 35MiB/sec, even on the host's esxcli, despite running on quite beefy DELL PERC controllers and storage that could handle 10x that.

Comment: Sounds like the buffer pool might be exhausted on the server. Did you guys try to restart SQL Server service? What version are you using?

Comment: I'd guess it's a slow disk (or disk controller etc), or possibly slow network. What happens if you just do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp` if that returns slow as well then it's the disk, otherwise its the network.

Comment: Seems like you and [IDeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22316223/ideal) are competing for the [task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78104493/2029983). Maybe instead work together and figure out the problem; you are both being payed by the same employer

Comment: Is one of those columns of yours containing xml? I had the same issue! Showing those columns took ages but working on them was fast...

Comment: In addition to what everyone else said, and related to the last comment, how big is a single row?...are there large columns (LOBs, columns with `MAX` data type, XML, `IMAGE`, etc). It's interesting one person ran out of Memory rendering the results (which would be on the client side most likely).